# How to Open github open source in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to open this project from GitHub

https://github.com/Shouheng88/MarkNote

but I can't do "Run" or preview XML file in Android Studio please help me

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1 - go to your link [here](https://github.com/Shouheng88/MarkNote)

2 - click on `Clone or download` box (it is green)

3 - click on `Download zip` and download it

4 - after extract go to your android studio > File > new > Import Project